# Scheduled task "Daily every" not firing

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I have the developers edition of CF running on my machine, and I have a job that is scheduled to run:

```
Daily every 9 min(s) from 12:01 AM to 12:59 PM
```

but it's not running.
I can press the "Run Scheduled Task" button and it runs, but it's not running on it's own.

I have other jobs that run daily, but this one is not running every 9 minutes.

Comment: There are only 8 minutes between 12:01 and 12:59.

Comment: What happens if you use a smaller range, like 3PM - 5PM?

Comment: What's your start date? What did you put in for end date?

Comment: How about removing the end time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the scheduler.log file for its execution and the next rescheduling time. If it hows a time which is not what you have set. Delete the job and recreate it again.

I have faced the same problem! and this was the way I made it running.

Comment: It started working when I said 00:01 to 23:59 instead of saying 12:01 AM - 12:59 PM.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out what's going on with the job is to take a look at the scheduler log in the CF Admin. After running the job, you should be able to check and see the next time it's scheduled to run.

Also, make sure the job isn't paused on the Scheduled Tasks page.